# Placed with BarLegend changes MousePosition response

Tags: legending, dynamic

```
DensityPlot[.015 Sin[x + y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(z\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(x\)]\)"}, 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 380]]
```

creates the plot
[image: Plot with BarLegend]

and `Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]` displays the position of the mouse on the plot, with coordinates between 0 and Pi.  However, if I replace `BarLegend` in the code above by `Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 380], {{1.0, 0.955}, {0.4, 1.0}}]`, the range of coordinates displayed by `MousePosition` changes to between 0 and a number or order 0.94.  How do I modify my code or otherwise work around this issue?  (Observing the maximum values from `MousePosition` and using them to rescale the results seems neither robust nor elegant.)  By the way, using `Placed` also changes the size of the plot.

Comment: maybe something like `Placed[BarLegend[Automatic,LegendMarkerSize -> 380], {Scaled@{1.02, 0.97}, Scaled@{0.3, .95}}]`? or `{Scaled@{1.03, 0.97}, {0.4, 1.0}}`

Comment: @kguler, could you explain why does that work, perhaps in an answer? (It sure does, I've tested! But I have no idea why...)

Comment: @Aisamu, I wish I knew why:) I just confirmed the issue (that, _for some reason_, `Placed` does change `MousePosition["Graphics"]` to `MousePosition["GraphicsScaled"]`), played with a few possible work-arounds, and found one that seemed to work:)

Comment: @kguler, Oh no, you were my hope! Hm.. I've tried `Placed[... , After]` and it did work as expected. It's only when specific (non-scaled) coordinates are used that things break. Even the ImageSize behavior changes, accounting for the whole image instead of only the plot part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I modify my code or otherwise work around this issue?

Using `Scaled` in the last argument of `Placed` seems to fix the issue:

```
DensityPlot[.015 Sin[x + y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> False, Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(z\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(x\)]\)"},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 50}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
 PlotLabel -> Dynamic@Style[Grid[{{"MousePosition[\"Graphics\"]  ", MousePosition["Graphics"]},
       {"MousePosition[\"GraphicsScaled\"]  ", MousePosition["GraphicsScaled"]}}], 16, "Panel"],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 380],
                      {Scaled[{1.04, 0.99}], {0.4, 1.0}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of the coordinates used in `Placed`? `{{x,y}, {sizeX, sizeY}}`? The documentation says "explicit lists of scaled coordinates", but I'd expect only `{x,y}`!

Comment: @Aisamu, if it helps, in the `Details` section there is this: `Placed[expr,{pos,epos}] specifies that position epos in expr should be placed at relative position pos.`

Comment: Thanks, @kguler.  I now see that `BarLegend` creates two graphics objects side by side, while `Placed` with `BarLegend` merges the two into one, evidently disabling the `"Graphics"` option.  Why applying `Scaled` to one or both coordinate pairs reenables the option remains unclear to me.  Perhaps, it has something to do with the `Scaled` Details statement, "You can use Scaled to represent objects that occupy a fixed region in a plot, independent of the specific range of coordinates in the plot."  In any case, it certainly works.